# Conditional Counting in Groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has stock tickers and a models accuracy for various dates that looks like this:

```
ZAYO  20170228  0.203997
ZAYO  20170531  0.180037
ZAYO  20170831  0.110623
ZBH   20170131  0.130060
ZBH   20170430  0.115384
ZBH   20170731  0.065990
AAAP  20170331  1.075765
AAAP  20170630  1.119365
AAAP  20170930  0.223602
AAL   20170131  0.338255
AAL   20170430  0.386442
AAL   20170731  0.171351
```

I want to create a summary data frame where each row contains ticker name, average accuracy, % of times where accuracy is above 20, % of times where accuracy is above 50%.

I use

```
dfGrouped = df.groupby(['tickers'])
dfGrouped.Accuracy.mean()
```

to get the average accuracy but not sure of a clean way to count how many times the accuracy for a particular ticker was above 20%, 50%.

Comment: Maybe filter it first: `dfGrouped = df[df.Accuracy>0.2].groupby(['tickers'])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a dictionary of calculations:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df.columns=['ticker', 'date', 'accuracy']

groupers = OrderedDict([('mean', np.mean),
                        ('>_0.20_pct', lambda x: (x > 0.20).sum()/len(x)),
                        ('>_0.50_pct', lambda x: (x > 0.50).sum()/len(x)),
                        ('>_0.70_pct', lambda x: (x > 0.70).sum()/len(x))])

res = df.groupby('ticker')['accuracy'].agg(groupers)

print(res)

            mean  >_0.20_pct  >_0.50_pct  >_0.70_pct
ticker                                              
AAAP    0.806244    1.000000    0.666667    0.666667
AAL     0.298683    0.666667    0.000000    0.000000
ZAYO    0.164886    0.333333    0.000000    0.000000
ZBH     0.103811    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! When I add another column like >0.7_pct to the end, it changes the order of the columns in the res dataframe. The order becomes 0.7, mean, 0.2, 0.5. Is there a way to specify order within that operation itself?

Comment: @bloodynri, Sure, see update. You can use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: This piece of code saved me hours and hours of cumbersome manipulation. thank you very much!

Comment: For anyone else who found this lovely snippet but encountered "SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported": the columns are renamed here with a dict appears to have be deprecated in 20.1. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-group-agg-dict

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dfGrouped.where(dfGrouped.Accuracy < 0.20).Accuracy.count()
```